# Graph API Nested Request Response

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to all day to find a solution and I can't so you are my last hope!
I use FB.api for a nested request and I got the response (checked console.log already and the response is ok). The problem is that when I'm trying to access the data of the response I'm getting and undefined error like the response is empty.
The function. When I 'm trying to get for example response length i'm getting an nothing. Any ideas? This is the error i'm getting from console.log
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"likes.limit(100) {link,picture}"},
  function(response) {
if (response == "undefined" || response == null || !response || response.error)
    {
        alert("error occured");
        return;
    }
    console.log(response);
  for (var l = response.data.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
}});
```

Part of the response

```
 {
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/G-Pappas-1881854208706899/",
        "picture": {
          "data": {
            "is_silhouette": false,
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xlp1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1909968_1936509979907988_8060180335068327040_n.jpg?oh=368e10a9ab58ad0f337647ec6187f204&oe=5723AD5D"
          }
        },
        "id": "1881854208706899"
      },
      {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/FOODMATES-112425739139239/",
        "picture": {
          "data": {
            "is_silhouette": false,
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xpt1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12565389_129926077389205_1734904915451564294_n.jpg?oh=e76b99b775f94a9291a8d3f97aaead06&oe=5727BF7C"
          }
        },
        "id": "112425739139239"
      },
      {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/ARKAS-The-Original-Page-352589524877216/",
        "picture": {
          "data": {
            "is_silhouette": false,
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xta1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1381313_352855468183955_671412865_n.jpg?oh=8bbdbfce5d0e34a1120ca9b3e3d1c22d&oe=576B0804"
          }
        },
        "id": "352589524877216"
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Looks like your not using the correct dot notation for the response.

The data array is nested inside likes. so to access the data you will need:
**response.likes.data.length**.

So to use it, try something like this:

```
  console.log(response);
  for (var l = response.likes.data.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      response.likes.data[i]
  }
```

Edit :  Here is a jsfiddle Link with an example of the correct dot notation with the information taken out : https://jsfiddle.net/b7r2qtre/

Comment: Cheesus Christ!! So many hours, I tried everything else except this!!
Thank you!!!!

Comment: No problem! sometimes when you stare at the same code for hours its hard to see the problem!